# What does 台 mean when proceeded by a number (of yen)

Tags: kanji, meaning

I came across this phrase in a [news article](http://www.minato-yamaguchi.co.jp/yama/news/digest/2012/0125/2.html) about a budget reduction:

> ．．．．６千億円台になる．．．．

I was wondering what this use of `台` means. I did a Google search of `円台` and the amount of yen doesn't seem to have an effect on when this is used. It seams to me to be used like a counter, but a price isn't really a machine...or is it (/cue dramatic music)?

My best guess is that it's means something like "an allotted amount", i.e. "You have X amount to spend, like it or not."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

「[台]{だい}」= the mark, level.

e.g.「[今年度]{こんねんど}の[利益]{りえき}は2[億円台]{おくえんだい}に[達]{たっ}した」= This year's profit reached the two hundred million yen mark.